# I keep getting the error "photos Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"". What does this mean, and how can I fix this?

Tags: ios, swift, share, gif, photo

When sharing an image, more specifically a large gif, I get the error
 `photos Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"`
What does this mean, and how can I fix this?

Here's a stubbed version of my code's save function, only leaving the parts related to gifs.

```swift
@IBAction func saveAction(_ sender: Any) {
        ....
                else{
                    //Save the image
                    prefs.set(currentPics, forKey: "numPics")
                    if let content = extensionContext!.inputItems[0] as? NSExtensionItem {
                        print(content.description)
                        let contentType = kUTTypeImage as String
                        let gifType = kUTTypeGIF as String
                        if let contents = content.attachments {
                            for attachment in contents {
                                var isGif=false
                                //Check for gif
                                if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(gifType) {
                                    isGif=true
                                    attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: contentType, options: nil) { data, error in
                                        let url = data as! URL
                                            if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                                                self.saveImage(imageData: imageData, isGif: isGif, fileURL: url)
                                            }

                                    }
                                }
                                    //Not a gif
                                ...........



            }
        }
    }

    func saveImage(imageData: Data, isGif: Bool, fileURL: URL) {
        let ArchiveURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:suiteName)!
        do{
            let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory( at: ArchiveURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
            let pngFiles = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "png" }
            let gifFiles = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "gif" }
            let number = pngFiles.count+gifFiles.count
            .......
                else{
                    //Insert code to handle resizing here

                    print("HERE WE GO")
                    let parameters = [
                        "version": "1",
                        "mode": "resize"
                    ]
                    do{
                        print("contacting server")
                    }
                    try imageData.write(to: ArchiveURL.appendingPathComponent("tmp.gif"), options: Data.WritingOptions.atomic)
                    Alamofire.upload(
                        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                            multipartFormData.append(fileURL, withName: "gif")
                            for (key, value) in parameters {
                                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
                            }
                    },
                        to: "https://my.heroku.app.link",
                        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                            switch encodingResult {
                            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                                upload.validate()
                                upload.responseData { response in
                                    let responseValue = response.result.value
                                    let dispatchWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem{
                                        print("work item start")
                                        print("work item end")
                                    }
                                    self.delay(bySeconds: 10, dispatchLevel: .main, closure: dispatchWorkItem)
                                    do {
                                        //Check for errors
                                        var dataString = String(data: response.data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                                        print(dataString)
                                        if dataString == "error"{
                                            do{
                                                print("error")
                                            }
                                        }

                                        else{
                                        //If it's not, save it
                                            print("Writing")
                                            print(responseValue?.description)
                                            print(responseValue!.isImageData)
                                            if responseValue!.isImageData{
                                                try responseValue!.write(to: filename, options: Data.WritingOptions.atomic)
                                                if let prefs = UserDefaults(suiteName: self.suiteName) {
                                                    var currentPics=prefs.integer(forKey: "numPicks")
                                                    print(currentpics)
                                                    currentPics+=1
                                                    prefs.set(currentPics, forKey: "numPics")
                                                    print(currentPics)
                                                }
                                                do{
                                                    print("Saved")
                                                }
                                            }
                    ..........
}
```

The odd thing is that sometimes, it will just work. But most of the time, it will say not permitted.